# Run new Magento ImportExport from shell

Tags: magento, import, export

does anyone have an idea, how it's possible to run the new ImportExport profile (e.g. for products or customer export) from shell?

I don't mean dataflow, but the new export routine from Mage_ImportExport module.

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a link to the further discussion on this matter: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/64276/run-new-magento-importexport-from-shell/64281#64281